# What to do to enable Websocket Steam on Ethereum Node Server for NodeJS endpoint API

Tags: websocket

I have Ethereum node by providing ws and http port access through windows server, I filter the data and get the data I want.I created the node.js api endpoint to provide this data, so I can apply my filters and access only the data I need thanks to this api. My system works fine when I run my project through the browser, I can see the output as HTTP as json output.

I want to create websocket live steam feature for this api ws: // localhost what can I do for this please inform me which shows the correct way (which npm I will use - I just want it to push the function I filtered in my project) Thanks a lot

my goal is to make this api project connect with WS:// ip in a different project. so why ı need websocket it can be listen this api steam...